# Is SimpleDateFormat parse - Daylight Saving Time Aware?

Tags: java, date, timezone, dst

I would like to know if the following is DST aware ie., the SimpleDateFormat parse method is DST aware if we set the Timezone of that respective country.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET")); //Germany
String currentDate = sdf.format((new Date()).getTime());
currentDate = sdf.parse(currentDate);
```

I undserstand that "CET", "MST", "EST" etc are three letter codes and is not encouraged to use this, but irrespective of this is the dateformat parse DST aware ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done to try this for yourself? What does `TimeZone.useDaylightTime` return?

Comment: It is returing true john for the ones that have daylight saving like CET,EST and is returning false for HST and JST

Comment: So can i safely say that using SDF parse which has a Timezone implementation that is DST aware will return time considering and offsetting DST ?

Comment: Yes. And if you're not necessarily convinced, again you can just try it...

Comment: From your comment above, and my answer below, I would be surprised if EST is returning true. [It returns false for me](http://ideone.com/UmGrNm).  Can you check again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some specific cases, the three-letter codes will work - but not all of them include daylight saving time rules.

From the TZ database sources:

[Europe](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/38e46697d8d5782c0f4b3c8a52a7fb44700ddfb6/europe#L627-L631):

```
# Zone  NAME    GMTOFF  RULES  FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    WET     0:00    EU     WE%sT
Zone    CET     1:00    C-Eur  CE%sT
Zone    MET     1:00    C-Eur  ME%sT
Zone    EET     2:00    EU     EE%sT
```

[North America](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/38e46697d8d5782c0f4b3c8a52a7fb44700ddfb6/northamerica#L148-L151):

```
# Zone  NAME    GMTOFF  RULES  FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    EST      -5:00  -      EST
Zone    MST      -7:00  -      MST
Zone    HST     -10:00  -      HST
```

As you can see, the European file defines 4 three-letter zones for backwards compatibility purposes, all of which follow European daylight saving time rules.

However, the North American file only defines 3 of these.  Notably, PST and CST are missing.  Also, the EST and MST zones that are defined do *not* have any daylight saving time rules.

In general, you should avoid using the three-letter abbreviations.  They are not *all* supported, the ones that are do not *all* support DST, and in general [they can be ambiguous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

Comment: Whoa, Ill double check this again.